# In ESP-12E NodeMCU, what's the pin number of A0?

Tags: esp8266, arduino-ide, nodemcu

In ESP-12E NodeMCU, all digital pins can be called with a number. Here is the list:

```
static const uint8_t D0   = 16; 
static const uint8_t D1   = 5;
static const uint8_t D2   = 4;
static const uint8_t D3   = 0;
static const uint8_t D4   = 2; 
static const uint8_t D5   = 14;
static const uint8_t D6   = 12;
static const uint8_t D7   = 13;
static const uint8_t D8   = 15;
static const uint8_t D9   = 3;
static const uint8_t D10  = 1;
```

So these two lines of code will do the same:

```
pinMode (D0, INPUT)
pinMode (16, INPUT)
```

What's the corresponding number for A0 (the only analog input of this board)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The numeric value of `A0` is 17, as defined [here](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/2.3.0/variants/generic/common.h#L45).

But unlike on an Arduino board, you can't use it as a digital pin. [It only work for pin numbers 0-16](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/2.3.0/cores/esp8266/core_esp8266_wiring_digital.c#L79).

If you are using as a parameter for `analogRead`, the numeric values would be 0 and 17, as seen [here](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/2.3.0/cores/esp8266/core_esp8266_wiring_analog.c#L32).

And as such, these three calls would do the same:

```cpp
analogRead(A0);
analogRead(17);
analogRead(0);
```